# Compare Strings in C inside an iteration?

Tags: c

I need to create this program in C and before i accepted simply an ID and compared the ID in the List with the given ID, which worked fine. However, i need to compare the name of a city instead of the id. How does that work in C?

Old code:

```
// Finds a city in a given CityList with an integer id.
City *findCity(CityList *cl, int id)
{
    int i;


   
    City *s = NULL;


    for (i = 0; i < cl->count; i++)
        if (cl->city[i]->cityId == id))
        {
 
            s = cl->city[i];
        }

    return s;
}
```

So this worked just fine, however, i need to find a city by using an string (char *) to check if its in the list. Any ideas?

My approach:

```
City *findCity(CityList *cl, char *name)
{
    int i;


   
    City *s = NULL;


    for (i = 0; i < cl->count; i++)
        if (cl->city[i]->cityId == name))
        {
 
            s = cl->city[i];
        }

    return s;
}
```

Which isn't working as i saw that you can't use == in C.

Comment: Of course you can use `==` in C. But you need to use `strcmp` and friends if you want to compare the contents of 2 NUL terminated `const char` arrays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: Got it. I tried strcmp before and tried to check if its 0, however, i could just make it inside my if statement.